# Spring Rest Template - Response Body Is Null

Tags: java, spring, nginx, resttemplate

I am using Spring Rest template when talking to rest webservices in my application.
In test the code works perfectly but in the production environment, my cpde is not working as the body coming back is null

I tried the following

```
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        RegisterUserRequestVO registerUserRequestVO = new RegisterUserRequestVO();
        registerUserRequestVO.setName(name);
ResponseEntity<String> resp  = hubsRestTemplate.postForEntity(getFullURLNoKeys(URL_POST_REGISTER_USER), registerUserRequestVO, String.class, params);
        System.out.println("resp:" + resp);
        System.out.println("resp:" + resp.getBody());
        System.out.println("resp:" + resp.getStatusCode());
        System.out.println("resp:" + resp.getHeaders());
        System.out.println("resp:" + resp.getHeaders());
```

The resp I get back in test is as follows

```
<200 OK,{"message":"Account created succesfuly"},{Server=[nginx/1.1.19], Date=[Fri, 10 Apr 2015 14:58:37 GMT], Content-Type=[application/json], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Connection=[keep-alive], Vary=[Accept-Encoding], X-Powered-By=[PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.17]}>
```

While in production the resp is

```
<200 OK,{Server=[nginx/1.6.0], Date=[Fri, 10 Apr 2015 15:00:03 GMT], Content-Type=[application/json], Connection=[close], Vary=[Accept-Encoding]}>
```

The response body returned is null. I understand the nginx versions are different but this is outside my control

Any help on this is greatly appreciated

Cheers
Damien

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in this post
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8016

I was on Spring version 4.1.4.RELEASE
Upgrading to Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE fixed the issue

Cheers
Damien

Comment: I was affected by the same bug and I would like to point out the fact that the responses with the header  **Connection=[close]**  were having a null body, as opposed to the ones having **Connection=[keep-alive]**

Comment: Facing the same problem with Spring version 4.2.5.RELEASE